# How to programmatically mount WebDAV on Ubuntu without installing davfs2?

Tags: ubuntu, webdav, gnome, mount

I need to programmatically mount WebDAV folder on Ubuntu. I have found a solution using davfs2.

However davfs2 is not installed by default on Ubuntu. At the same time Gnome 'Places->Connect to Server...' menu can do this without installing davfs2. I assume it also does not require root privileges.

Any ideas how to mount WebDAV without installing davfs2?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool that is already on Ubuntu installs: `nd`. But this requires to enter the username and password all the time.

If you can build from source a WebDAV client like [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/)

You can use the `--prefix` option at `configure` and select a folder you have write access:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/me/cadaver/
make
make install
```

`cadaver`  supports  automatically  logging in to servers requiring authentication via a .netrc file

Comment: As far as I see davfs2 is not installed, "sudo mount -t davfs2 'http://server/' /share/" returns 'unknown file system type davfs2'. But 'Places->Connect to Server...' still works.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a [cadaver package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cadaver&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) available for all currently supported releases so compiling isn't required. You can install it with the command `sudo apt-get install cadaver` As mentioned by [JScoobyCed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012381/jscoobyced) "cadaver supports automatically logging in to servers requiring authentication via a .netrc file"

Here's a couple excerpts from the man page:

```
THE .netrc FILE
       The file ~/.netrc may be  used  to  automatically  login  to  a  server
       requiring  authentication.  The  following tokens (separated by spaces,
       tabs or newlines) may be used:

       machine host
              Identify a remote machine host which is compared with the  host‐
              name  given  on  the  command line or as an argument to the open
              command.  Any subsequent tokens up to the end  of  file  or  the
              next machine or default token are associated with this entry.

       default
              This  is  equivalent  to the machine token but matches any host‐
              name. Only one default token may be used and it  must  be  after
              all machine tokens.

       login username
              Specifies  the  username  to  use  when logging in to the remote
              machine.

       password string
       passwd string
              Specifies the password to use when  logging  in  to  the  remote
              machine.

       Any other tokens (as described in ftp(1)) are ignored.


EXAMPLES
       cadaver http://dav.example.com/
              Connects to the server myserver.example.com, opening the root collection.

   cadaver http://zope.example.com:8022/Users/fred/
          Connects to the server zope.example.com using port 8022, opening the collection "/Users/fred/".

   cadaver https://secure.example.com/
          Connects to a server called secure.example.com using SSL.

FILES
       ~/.cadaverrc
              Individual user settings that can override cadaver defaults and to script cadaver. Can be changed by the "--rcfile" option.

       ~/.netrc
              Login and initialization information used by the auto-login process. See section "THE .netrc FILE" for details.
```